# Error: Introspection result missing interfaces: { kind: "OBJECT", name: "Address", fields: [[Object], [Object],

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to render my graphql schema so I can use it in a xcode/swift projet with Apollo.
When I run this:

```
apollo schema:download --endpoint=http://localhost:5880/graphql schemas.json
```

I get this error:

```
 Saving schema to schemas.json
    → Introspection result missing interfaces: { kind: "OBJECT", name: "Address", fields: [[Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [O
…
    Error: Introspection result missing interfaces: { kind: "OBJECT", name: "Address", fields: [[Object], [Object], [Object],
    [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]] }
```

Here is the type Address definition:

```
type Address {
    id: ID
    addressOne: String
    addressTwo: String
    city: String
    state: String
    zipCode: String
    addressType: String
}
```

I'm able to query my graphql schema via postman and graphiql without any issues. The Apollo tool seems to be having issues understanding my schema. Here is the full schema deffinition:

```
type Query {
    userById(id: ID): User
}

type Mutation {
    register(register: RegistrationModel): Registration
}

input RegistrationModel {
    companyName: String
    name: String
    middleName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
    phone: String
    username: String
    password: String
    confirmPassword: String
    businessName: String
    legalAgreementVerified: Boolean
}

type Registration {
    userId: String
    companyName: String
    name: String
    middleName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
    phone: String
    username: String
    password: String
    confirmPassword: String
    businessName: String
    legalAgreementVerified: Boolean
    hasError: Boolean
    usernameError: String
    nameError: String
    lastNameError: String
    emailError: String
    phoneError: String
    confirmPasswordError: String
    legalAgreementVerifiedError: String
    passwordError: String
}

type User {
    id: ID
    middleName: String
    lastName: String
    phone: String
    username: String
    name: String
    addressId: String
    email: String
    legalAgreementVerified: Boolean
    emailVerified: Boolean
    addressVerified: Boolean
    invoicePaymentDueInDays: Int
    sessionLengthInMinutes: Int
    cancelDate: String
    lastLogin: String
    lastUpdatedDate: String
    createdDate: String
    address: Address
    locale: String
    sessionDefaultCost: Float
    password: String
    oldPassword: String
    businessName: String
    fullName: String
    clients(id: ID): [Client]
}

type Parent {
    id: ID
    name: String
    client: Client
}

type Invoice {
    id: ID
    amountPaid: Float
    total: Float
    client: Client
    invoiceBillables: [Billable]
}

type Client {
    id: ID
    name: String
    middleName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
    phone: String
    status: String
    addressId: String
    fullName: String
    billables: [Billable]
    invoices(id: ID): [Invoice]
    clientAddress: Address
    parents: [Parent]
}

type Billable {
    id: ID
    user: User
    client: Client
    invoice: Invoice
    givenName: String
}

type Address {
    id: ID
    addressOne: String
    addressTwo: String
    city: String
    state: String
    zipCode: String
    addressType: String
}
```

I'm new to Apollo and Swift. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

I've tried multiple tools queries my graphql schema and they were all succesfull tests. I've also tried re arranging the Address definition. Simplifying the object as much as possible. Nothing worked.

Comment: What's the server that's hosting this GraphQL endpoint? I suspect you have the [introspection API](https://graphql.org/learn/introspection/) disabled, which is what Apollo (and other clients) need in order to ask what types, fields, etc. exist in your schema.